# How can I use type key as enum?

Tags: typescript, type-erasure

eg I have

```
type typeA = "A1" | "A2" | "A3";
```

then I want to use type value direction

```
typeA.A1; // "A1"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm confused. You can't use [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), or am I missing something?

Comment: okay, that might work, cause there is already a type, and it is maintained by 3rd party.

Comment: You don't need `typeA.A1`. Just use `"A1"`. This is a string literal type, there is no need to use an indirection on the value — using the literal is type safe.

Comment: @IngoBürk is correct. The whole point of an union type such as `typeA` is simply to constrain the values you are allowed to assign to a variable with that type. `typeA` doesn't represent a namespace. In fact, because of [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types), `typeA` will not even exist in the generated Javascript and thus not at runtime!  But I'll write up an alternative *in case* you can convince the third party to adopt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can't use a type alias as an enum because of [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types). `typeA` will not exist in the generated Javascript and thus not at runtime.[1]

Since you said in your comment that `typeA` "is maintained by 3rd party", there is nothing you can do. But also there is ***nothing you need to do:***

- Why would you write `typeA.A1` in your code when you could write `"A1"`? It's almost like defining `const TWO = 2` in your code and using `TWO` instead of the literal `2`.
- There is no additional type safety by using `typeA.A` instead of `"A1"`. Static type checking will prevent you from assigning/passing any values other that those allowed by `typeA` to any variables or parameters with that type.
- Any IDE that supports Typescript will auto suggest legal values for such variables and parameters.

### but let's say you really needed/wanted to be able to say `typeA.A1`...

The code will have to work the other way around: define Enum values (not necessarily using the `enum` syntax), and then define a type alias that represents the union of those values.

For example:

```js
enum A {A1 = "A1", A2 = "A2", A3 = "A3" }

// type typeA = "A1" | "A2" | "A3"
type typeA = keyof typeof A
```

Usage:

```js
function checkA(arg: typeA):void {
    console.log(arg)
}

checkA(A.A1)  //ok
checkA("A1")  //ok
checkA("A4")  //error

let v1: A = A.A1
let v2: typeA = "A1"
let v3: string = "A1"

checkA(v1)    //ok
checkA(v2)    //ok
checkA(v3)    //error
```

You could instead define the function arg as `arg: A`, but it would be even more strict, only accepting references to the `A` enum, not the string `"A1"` or the variable `v2`:

```js
function checkA(arg: A):void {
    console.log(arg)
}
```

You would have to convince the third party to make this change.

---

[1] There is [a nice table in the Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts) that summarize which things exist after transpiling to Javascript.